# Use insertAfter for each element within its parent

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following HTML markup:

```
<div class="form-item">
   <i>item 1</i>
   <div class="content">
      some content for item 1
   </div>
   <div class="description">
      some description for item 1
   </div>
</div>

<div class="form-item">
   <i>item 2</i>
   <div class="content">
      some content for item 2
   </div>
   <div class="description">
      some description for item 2
   </div>
</div>

<div class="form-item">
   <i>item 3</i>
   <div class="content">
      some content for item 3
   </div>
   <div class="description">
      some description for item 3
   </div>
</div>
```

and I want to insert `.description` after the related `<i>` tag within its parent. The problem is, that each `.description` gets inserted after to each `<i>`.

My attempt was:

```
$('.form-item .description').insertAfter('.form-item i');
```

but I only want to insert the related item `.description` within the parent after the `i`

How to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate over each of them and append to their sibling i tag element:

```
$('.form-item .description').each(function(){
  $(this).insertAfter($(this).prevAll('i'));
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1st36kz5/)**

Answer (score 0):

Or you can reverse the task with `$.fn.after` method:

```
$('.form-item i').after(function() {
    return $(this).siblings('.description');
});
```

Demo:

```js
$('.form-item i').after(function() {
    return $(this).siblings('.description');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-item">
   <i>item 1</i>
   <div class="content">
      some content for item 1
   </div>
   <div class="description">
      some description for item 1
   </div>
</div>

<div class="form-item">
   <i>item 2</i>
   <div class="content">
      some content for item 2
   </div>
   <div class="description">
      some description for item 2
   </div>
</div>

<div class="form-item">
   <i>item 3</i>
   <div class="content">
      some content for item 3
   </div>
   <div class="description">
      some description for item 3
   </div>
</div>
```